# Disable the autofocus on click in Google Chrome on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, focus

I am reading a diagnostic book and browsing pictures with my Samsung Galaxy S4. 
I do not like the autofocus on click in Google Chrome on Android.

How can you disable the autofocus on click in Google Chrome on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot because the big player do not need to do their best to satisfy minority customers. Change your internet browser: Yandex Browser should work.